# Pickled model with vectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am pickling a model for later use. Then loading the model and running `predict_proba` on it. I get `ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 319`. Not sure if I am transforming it correctly

```
import csv, pickle
from sklearn import svm

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
import numpy as np
import operator

train_data = []
train_labels = []
test_lables = []
test_lables.append("nah")

with open('training_file', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        train_data.append(row[0])
        train_labels.append(row[1])

lables = []

for item in train_labels:
    if item in lables:
        continue
    else:
        lables.append(item)


def linear_svc(train_data, train_labels):

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
    classifier_linear = svm.LinearSVC()
    clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(classifier_linear)   
    clf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)

    with open('test', 'wb') as fi:
        pickle.dump(clf, fi)


def run_classifier():    
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    test_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(test_lables)
    with open('test', 'rb') as fi:
        clf = pickle.load(fi)
    prediction_linear = clf.predict_proba(test_vectors) 
    return prediction_linear


#linear_svc(train_data, train_labels)
sorted_intent_probability = run_classifier()
print(sorted_intent_probability)
```

I first call the `linear_svc()` method. The model gets pickled. Then I call `run_classifier()`. What am I doing wrong here? Also, when I combine both the methods, it works fine:

```
def linear_svc(train_data, train_labels, test_lables):

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
    test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(test_lables)
    classifier_linear = svm.LinearSVC()
    clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(classifier_linear) 

    clf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
    prediction_linear = clf.predict_proba(test_vectors)
    return prediction_linear
```

Do I need to pickle the vectorizer as well and reuse it later?

Comment: You should only call vectorizer.transform() on test labels. Currently you are refitting the vectorizer which will give different number of features.

Comment: @VivekKumar If I change vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data) to vectorizer.transform(train_data), I get 'sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. When I create new instance of `TfidfVectorizer()` I am not using the same features that were used for the training. I made following change

```
linear_svc_model = clf.fit(train_vectors, train_labels)
model_object = []
model_object.append(linear_svc_model)
model_object.append(vectorizer)
```

and pickled this model_object. Then while using unpickled both classifier and vectorizer and used the same on training string. It worked.